# I am unable to view profiles when doing a Google x-ray search for recruiting

Tags: operators, linkedin-api

I am trying to find profiles for frontend engineers doing a google x-ray search.  I have tried site:linkedin.com frontend engineer and it does not give me profiles like it does in examples of using this operator search.  How can I find LI profiles without using LI recruiter?

I have tried site:linkedin.com frontend engineer and it does not give me profiles like it does in examples of using this operator search.